# Scala compile time error: "could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm trying to compile my scala code. I have the above-mentioned error. This error goes away sometimes when I compile again.

Error at his line:

```
implicit val motionCollectionsEncoder =
  jsonEncoderWithPrinterOf[MotionCollections](
    Printer.noSpaces.copy(dropNullKeys = true)
  )
```

Link to the package Circe: http://agourlay.github.io/cornichon/api/org/http4s/circe/index.html

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: Do you have an error if you use `sbt clean compile` command?

Comment: More context would be useful here.

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc even with that command I get this error.

Comment: @AswiniV and do you have works/doesn't work behaviour with SBT command too? Or it does not work all the time?

Comment: @TravisBrown, This motionCollectionsEncoder is being used in an different scala file.

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc, when I recompile second or third time, it is working. I also notice today when I clear the cache or close the IDE and use the cmd line, it compiles. Now my worry is if the IntelliJ IDEA is causing this issue??

Comment: @AswiniV it might be the case that idea is causing this. Try removing all idea files, like .idea folder,  re-importing your SBT project and see if the problem persists